# Access createjs functions outside the animatecc script

Tags: javascript, frame-rate, createjs

I'm now searching for quite a while on this subject and it seems no solution to this issue is available. However, before closing the case I wanted to illustrate the problem here as a last step, to assure I've not missed anything.
**The problem:** I have an adobean animatecc graphic that is embedded in an iframe element. The graphic has been created by an editor at a company I'm currently working at. My supervisor now wants me to stop the animation from outside this created animatecc graphic. So basically I want to get access to the Ticker element, that holds information about the fps rate in order to change it's value and therefore get the animation to stop. 
Anyhow, it seems that it's just not possible to intervein into this graphic after it was generated from the adobe tool. Does anyone of you has had the same issue and was able to solve it?

It would be of great help if someone would have any solution or suggestion to address this problem.

Thanks in advance guys,
have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

All right, 
as it always is, after posting the issue I now have found a solution that works and I thought I'd share it here in case anyone runs into having a similar problem.

Solution:

After the iframe has rendered the animatecc graphic you have an `adobean` object that you can work with 
`adobean = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.AdobeAn`

This object has a function `getComposition`, which lets you get some components of the `animatecc element`.

One component is the stage component, which can be retrieved via a `getStage()` call. The stage itself has children nodes, one of them is the tickEnabled boolean attribute.

`adobean.getComposition(adobean.bootcompsLoaded[0]).getStage().children[0].tickEnabled = false;` 
This line of code visualises what I've just described. When setting the value to false, the animation will stop.

Important is that you wait for the iframe until it has been loaded, as this adobean will be undefined elsewise.

So I hope this may help one of you, it sure as hell would have saved me one week of researching.

Have a great day!

Comment: Glad you solved it. My answer might be a better "official" approach, but this is also a good way to control or modify Animate content dynamically :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the same domain, you should be able to access the embedded iframe context.

```
var context = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;
```

From there it should be as simple as resetting the Ticker. The `createjs` object is a global object in the window, which all CreateJS content resides.

```
context.createjs.Ticker.reset();
```

You also mentioned reducing the framerate -- that *might* work as well:

```
context.createjs.Ticker.timingMode = "interval"; // Required as RAF can't change framerate
context.createjs.Ticker.framerate = 0.0001; // 0 will cause a division by 0 error probably
```

- [docs on reset](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Ticker.html#method_reset)
- [docs on Ticker](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Ticker.html)

One last note: Ticker does support "pause", but it doesn't actually stop ticking, it is up to the developer to implement the pausing based on the Ticker event.

Hope that helps!